# SQL - joining tables together for a single table

Tags: sql

Noob question - I have the following tables;

ID is Unique as well as date & time.

How can I write an SQL query that will return a table with;

```
   COLUMNS: id, man
```

Pretty sure I'm being extra stupid but losing patience rapidly with what appears to be so simple.

Comment: Do *not* tag every DBMS product.  Tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.price
FROM film t1
JOIN movie t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select film.id, date, time, price
from film
join movie on (film.id = movie.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The queries given in previous answers are correct and will give you what you want, but it may be worth explaining a bit:

Since these tables aren't necessarily related, the `JOIN` you're doing here is a `LEFT JOIN` - you'll notice in your results that you get all the rows from both tables, with `NULL` values on the left or right side where there is no match between `film.ID` and `movie.ID`.

Similarly, where the `ID` columns match, (ex. `film.ID = 1` and `movie.ID = 1`), you'll receive the full data inline for both tables.

If you wanted to filter on this data, the tables would need to share a relationship somehow, for example: a `MovieID` column on the `Film` table. With this, you could do:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Film f
    INNER JOIN Movie m ON f.MovieID = m.ID
```

This query would return the results from `Film` and `Movie` where `f.MovieID` matches the `ID` of the `Movie` table, excluding other results.

For additional information, [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) is a good explanation of the different types SQL joins.

Answer (score 0):

I might do it a little differently, since movie may contain more records than price (i.e., a movie exists, whether or not there's a price associated):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.price
FROM movie t1
LEFT JOIN film t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```